# amp-carousel has nested a tag in not matching documentation causing SEO issues

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, amp-html

This side-effect is undesirable as affecting SEO.

Current outputted markup for amp-carousel is:

```
<amp-carousel width="620" height="404" type="slides" layout="responsive" class="i-amphtml-layout-responsive i-amphtml-layout-size-defined" i-amphtml-layout="responsive">
   <i-amphtml-sizer style="display:block;padding-top:65.1613%;"></i-amphtml-sizer>

   <figure class="slide">
      <a href="https://website.com/image">
         <amp-img width="620" height="413" src="https://ebsite.com/image/wp-content/uploads/sites/12/2020/07/Gjen-Betty-Peppino-Lapadula-60th-wedding_35921230-846x564.jpg" class="attachment-large size-large amp-wp-enforced-sizes i-amphtml-layout-fill i-amphtml-layout-size-defined" alt="" aria-describedby="gallery-2-1461806" layout="fill" object-fit="cover" disable-inline-width="" i-amphtml-layout="fill">
            <noscript><img width="620" height="413" src="https://website.com/image/wp-content/uploads/sites/12/2020/07/Gjen-Betty-Peppino-Lapadula-60th-wedding_35921230-846x564.jpg" class="attachment-large size-large" alt="" loading="lazy" aria-describedby="gallery-2-1461806"  sizes="(max-width: 620px) 100vw, 620px"></noscript>
         </amp-img>
      </a>
      <figcaption class="amp-wp-gallery-caption">
         Betty and Peppino Lapadula.
      </figcaption>
   </figure>
   
  
   <figure class="slide">
      <a href="https://website.com/image/">
         <amp-img width="620" height="404" src="https://website.com/image/wp-content/uploads/sites/12/2020/07/Gjen-Betty-Peppino-Lapadula-60th-wedding_35921221-866x564.jpg" class="attachment-large size-large amp-wp-enforced-sizes i-amphtml-layout-fill i-amphtml-layout-size-defined" alt="" aria-describedby="gallery-2-1461815" layout="fill" object-fit="cover" disable-inline-width="" i-amphtml-layout="fill">
            <noscript><img width="620" height="404" src="https://website.com/image/wp-content/uploads/sites/12/2020/07/Gjen-Betty-Peppino-Lapadula-60th-wedding_35921221-866x564.jpg" class="attachment-large size-large" alt="" loading="lazy" aria-describedby="gallery-2-1461815" </noscript>
         </amp-img>
      </a>
      <figcaption class="amp-wp-gallery-caption">
         Betty and Peppino Lapadula.
      </figcaption>
   </figure>
</amp-carousel>
```

Whereas the [documentation](https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-carousel-v0.1/?format=websites) both v0.1 and v0.2 doesn't have this nested `<a>` tag.

```
        <script async custom-element="amp-carousel" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-carousel-0.2.js"></script>
```

I've created a custom template in an attempt to load the v0.2 script in the `<Head>` to "override" this possible v0.1/v0.0(?) `<amp-carousel>` however this hasn't worked.

The content for the AMP template is being pulled from this:

```
<div class="amp-wp-article-content">
        <?php $content = $this->get( 'post_amp_content' );
        echo $content;
        ?>
    </div>
```

So in addition to asking for advice on how to strip the `<a>` tags out of the carousel I am curious if there is a way to **edit** this `$content` before printing it?

I have tried to utilise `<amp-script>` however upon wrapping this div above it breaks the template so I'm unable to write simple js to strip the nested `<a>` tags.

I was originally of mind that this nested `<a>` was the result of the non-amp site using Lightbox however I have successfully managed to create an article which emulates the content with lightbox **turned off** so I am somewhat confident in ruling this out.

To summarise:

a) any help on how to edit the `$content` before post in an attempt to strip the nested `<a>` 's

b) how to address this `<amp-carousel>` issue when my custom template is using `$content` to print

c) `<amp-carousel>` not matching markup of documentation

Comment: did you tried `the_content` filter you can find example here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/

Comment: Are you using any plugin for slider?